# Multiple Select Dropdown list control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-controls

I am looking for a Mulitple select dropdown list in  asp.net where on select of one item other control also gets populated. I do not want to use 3rd party tool, suggest a control using Jquery or any thing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use List box for multiple selection:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Rows="1"></asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: I am looking for drop down list not List box .

Comment: Use update one . I added "Rows=1"